# Some Applications acts messy in MSI laptop

Tags: display, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

My MSI laptop display gets crazy but this happens only on some application like while using the Atom editor or VS code or only in Brave browser, this dont happen when using chrome or edge. I looked a lot online but cant figure out the problem. Its will be very helpful is someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is a pic while using VS code:
[image: Here is a pic while using VS code]

Comment: Did you try installing the newest Video driver?

Answer (score 1):

The first step when dealing with video artifacts like this is to update your graphics drivers, all system firmware, and your OS. If the issues tend to occur in specific programs, make sure these programs are fully up to date also.

If the programs offer switches controlling "GPU acceleration", set these to the opposite of whichever value they were previously (if they are currently enabled, set them to disabled, etc).

If these steps don't resolve the issue, then the issue is likely hardware related, even if it's only affecting a subset of your programs. It may be the methods of video projection employed by these applications are using a part of the GPU that is faulty or failing. Because individual sub-components of the GPU cannot be replaced, this still means the entire GPU, or the portion of the system the GPU is integrated into, will need to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by going to the properties and changing the compatibility to Windows 8 and its seems to work ok for now